# Careers PDF Export: github entry titles

Tags: bug, jobs, pdf

The formatting for GitHub projects on careers causes a line wrap a bit more prematurely than necessary when doing a PDF export.  I see a few potential fixes:

- Use a more concise format / smaller font for the dates, ie `Sep 2015-Oct 2015`
- Give us the option to just omit the url altogether. Anyone inclined to find the project on GitHub will be smart enough to do so without the full url.

[image]

Comment: *sigh* not a peep from anyone at Stack Exchange.  Is this product still being actively supported?